# Rails add cachebuster timestamp to SWF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I noticed javascript and images get a timestamp appended to its filename to prevent them from being cached when I use image_tag or javascript_tag. Is there to get this functionality for a swf file I have in /public/swf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
image_path('/swf/my.swf')
```

...will work, since you're passing an absolute URI to your SWF file, it will use the full public path helper logic including any configured cache-buster.

Comment: I went looking thru source code, and resolved it using compute_public_path('my.swf', 'swf'), which does exactly the same. But your solutions looks way better. Thanks.